# splitting a list of sentences into seperate words in a array

Tags: python

I have a list which consists of lines as

```
lines =  ['The query complexity']
```

I need to select each word in a separate line every time I start loop

```
lines =  ['The']
lines =  ['query']
lines =  ['complexity']
```

Please help me to obtain it as a list of seperate words.

```
for i in array:
    print(array[0].split())
```

Comment: You are not clear! Can you understand it? Which loop? Looping on what?

Comment: not sure what you want, you want to get each word in a separated list ?

Comment: what is `array` ?

Comment: `[[i] for i in array[0].split()]` but I don't understand why you'd want an array per word rather than just individual words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `lines` that you show only has one line in it, but I assume from your question that it could be multiple lines.  In that case, you need to loop over `lines` and then loop over the individual words within each line.

Copying your example, you could try the following:

```
for line in lines:
    for word in line.split():
        print(word)
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
lines =  ['The query complexity']
split = [word for word in lines[0].split(' ')]

for word in split:
    #your code
```